# Is there any way to capture if the values of series or sequence is becoming stagnant?

Tags: python, data-analysis, series

My goal is to monitor and check if the value of the data is becoming stagnant(neither incremental nor decremental).

Ex.

```
data = numpy.Series([1223.4,110.4,100.8,100.3,100.1,100,100,99,96,95,95,95,95,34])
```

Hereafter '96' there is a certain stagnancy in the data, which I want to capture over here. Note that after '100.1' the value did not change for the next two entries but I want a window of 3 entry, So if the value does not change for the consecutive three entries. we can mark it as stagnant.

I am expecting an output in this format  :

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0]
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This code will give the correct output

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([1223.4,110.4,100.8,100.3,100.1,100,100,99,96,95,95,95,95,34])
output = np.zeros (len(data))

def stagnant (data, output):

    prv = data[0]
    counter = 1
    
    for i in range (1, len(data)):
        if data[i] == prv:
            counter = counter + 1
        else:
            counter = 1
           
        if counter == 3 :
            for j in range (i, i-3, -1):
                output[j]=1
                
        elif counter > 3:
            output[i]=1

        prv = data[i]
        

stagnant(data, output)
print (output)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
```

Comment: I updated the code, the first one had a loose edge case. This updated code should work for any input